# unable to parse utf-8 data from mysql to php

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

unable to parse data in php from mysql in hindi on sharedhost

here's my code

```
  n variables
```

*/

```
define('DB_USER', "root"); // db user
define('DB_PASSWORD', ""); // db password (mention your db password here)
define('DB_DATABASE', "test"); // database name
```

define('DB_SERVER', "localhost"); // db server
    ?>

Thats all the code of all the functions included,It is giving perfect result when i am running it on locahost but giving errors which are mentioned above when i am running it on server,Kindly go through all this and help me out.
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your server is running PHP 5.4. `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` was added in PHP 5.4 so it looks like you need upgrade your version of PHP to take advantage of it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this SQL to set charset for results

```
mysql_query ("set character_set_results='utf8'");
```

And then execute other select statements.

Comment: i have tried these but still could'nt.can you try urself and share the code if it works.

Comment: Where exactly you used this statement. Before or after connecting to database ?

Comment: You can't do that on a shared host. Use this ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8');
 To change default_charset. But it is not best practice some other issues is there in you code. I can't help you until you give me more details

Comment: yeah i am getting issues on shared host error as "Warning: json_encode() expects parameter 2 to be long,"what else details you want" i m putting whole code by edit.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
mysql_set_charset("utf8");
```

And use `utf8_decode` (not utf8_encode), to get your results.
And also consider moving to Mysqli or PDO functions ;)

Comment: i have tried these but still could'nt.can you try urself and share the code if it works.